# Google Analytics Event Not Working - file download click event added dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

I have added a jquery snippet that attaches an event to all hrefs that open as pdf. I can see that it is firing but the event is never tracked in analytics

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
//attach event dispatcher to all links that are pdf files
//register event in analtyics

   $('a[href*=".pdf"]').click(function(e) {
       ga('send', 'event', 'PDF', 'download', 'digital content', $(this).attr('href'));
       console.log($(this).attr('href'));
    //console log is working each time link clicked
   });
});
```

Analytics code is added in head like such

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXX-YY');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

PDF docs linked:

```
<a href="http://website.com/50025H966.pdf" target="_blank" class="body_link_11">
http://website.com/50025H966.pdf<span class="icon_11 ui-icon-extlink"></span></a>
```

Tag manager not an option as I dont control that part of the site, I can only add js

Comment: How are you verifying that the event is never tracked in analytics? Are you allowing at least 24 hours for the data to be processed? Are you checking with GA Debugger, or real-time reports? One thing I notice is that you are sending in a non-integer value for the event value (the 6th parameter in your ga function). It should be an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing I notice is that you are sending in a non-integer value for the event value (the 6th parameter in your ga function). It should be an integer

```
ga('send', 'event', 'PDF', 'download', 'digital content', 1);
```

(cf. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events#implementation)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware you should only use 5 parameters (including send).

eg

`ga('send', eventCategory, eventAction, eventLabel, eventValue);`

based of your example I used this on my site and it works in the real time events with no problems

`ga('send', 'event', 'PDF', 'digital content', $(this).attr('href'));`

Comment: Hey, there, just wanted to mention that this is not correct as you need to send a hitType as the second parameter, eg. `event`, `pageview`, etc. Your second example would most definitely work as it's correct syntax. What I believe is the issue is that the `value` being sent isn't an integer.